# Twig do not set the locale in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, localization, twig

I created a EventListener to set the locale based on the user preferences, i set the langage like this in my listener:

```
$request->setLocale($user->getLanguage());

$request->getSession()->set('_locale',$user->getLanguage());
```

I tried both..

I register the Listener in the `service.yml`:

```
 app.event_listener.locale:
        class: 'AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener'
        arguments:
            - '@security.token_storage'
        tags:
            - {name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'kernel.request', method: 'onKernelRequest'}
```

I also tried to add a `priority: 17` to the service but it does not change anything...

The listener seems to works, i can get the Locale in my controller with a `$request->getLocale()`(or session).

But Twig is still in the default language I defined in the `config.yml`:

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
```

I'm pretty lost now, any tips ?

Comment: can You post services.yml with definition of this listener?

Comment: @mmmm I add the service.yml code, i tried to change the priority of the service without any success

Comment: how do you call it in your twig ?

Comment: @DOZ : I do something like : `_{{ 'user.list'  | trans({}, 'navigation') }}`

Comment: have you add the translation file corresponding to your translation ? (messages.en.yml if you set your local to 'en' for example)

Comment: @DOZ Yes i do have a ``messages.en.yml`

Comment: Have you this line in your config ? `framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }`

Comment: I have `framework: translator: { fallback: ["%locale%"] }` and `parameters: locale: fr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of stuff (change the priority, check if the locale is passed to the front etc...)
Finally i forced the translator in my EventListener:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if ($this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        if ($user && $user instanceof User) {
            $request->setLocale($user->getLanguage());
        } elseif ($request->query->has('locale')) {
            $request->setLocale($request->query->get('locale'));
        } else {
            $request->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage());
        }
    }
    $this->translator->setLocale($request->getLocale());
}
```

I don't understand why, this should be done in the Symfony translator, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the locale for the translator to get the right translation in templates.

E.g in controller:

```
$this->get('translator')->setLocale($user->getLanguage());
```